# No module named 'endless_pagination'

Tags: django, django-endless-pagination

I'm trying to setup endless_pagination, I've followed the documentation but getting an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
    raise e
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
    raise e
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 179, in <module>
    application = load_wsgi_application()
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 175, in load_wsgi_application
    return __import__(os.environ['WSGI_MODULE'], globals(), locals(), ['application']).application
  File "/var/www/khalid_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named 'endless_pagination'
```

I installed it using `easy_install -Z django-endless-pagination`, and added `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in the Settings.py context_processors (under TEMPLATES).

I added `'endless_pagination'` in the installed apps section of the Settings.py. These are the steps from the documentation, when I reload the server, I get `ImportError: No module named 'endless_pagination'`. What seems to be the problem here?

Any help/direction would be appreciated,

Thanks

INSTALLATION OUTPUT:

```
    (myvenv) 08:19 ~/mysite $ easy_install -Z django-endless-pagination
Searching for django-endless-pagination
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-endless-pagination/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/6e/82/27bac7a83a5aedb45d031edb5a0ce2f0f9c57b81254e4e162a6bbd94acfa/django-
endless-pagination-2.0.tar.gz#md5=8efa40cee51ebe229ce15ed258594ba0
Best match: django-endless-pagination 2.0
Processing django-endless-pagination-2.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-lsvk24ce/django-endless-pagination-2.0/setup.cfg
Running django-endless-pagination-2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lsvk24ce/django-endless-pagina
tion-2.0/egg-dist-tmp-3qtpwgoa
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating /home/khalid/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_endless_pagination-2.0-py3.5.egg
Extracting django_endless_pagination-2.0-py3.5.egg to /home/khalid/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Adding django-endless-pagination 2.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /home/khalid/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_endless_pagination-2.0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for django-endless-pagination
Finished processing dependencies for django-endless-pagination
```

Comment: Does `easy_install -Z django-endless-pagination` install package to _/usr/lib/python3.5_?

Comment: @vishes_shell It seems to have, according to the output when I used easy_install: `myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_endless_pagination-2.0-py3.5.egg`

Comment: No no no, you have installed into _myvenv/lib/python3.5/python_ so into your virtualenv, but you aretrying to run server with python that is not in your virtualenv. So you should acrivate your virtualenv and run the script again, it should work

Comment: @vishes_shell I only work on my virtual environment, I installed it in my virtual environment, and I'm still in that same session, I haven't even closed the console. I will edit my question and add the whole easy_install input/output.

Comment: Look at the path when you run `easy_install`: `/home/khalid/mysite/myvenv/lib/python3.5/`
And path from traceback with error: `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`

Comment: I tried again, from within the virtual environment, and this is the message I got: `(myvenv) 10:52 ~/mysite $ pip install django-endless-pagination
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-endless-pagination in ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-pack
ages/django_endless_pagination-2.0-py3.5.egg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122411/discussion-between-vishes-shell-and-almost-a-beginner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using Django 1.8 or newer, you must use this one: http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html (EL Pagination), endless paginations is deprecated in Django 1.8 and newers

Comment: Took your advise, installed EL Pagination, did the basic configuration and I got an error when reloading the server: `TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].insert(0, 'django.core.context_processors.request')
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: This solved the issue, my previous comment was quiet stupid. After checking the settings.py, I realized context_processors.request was already set, it was completely un-necessary to add that. The EL Pagination docs said to do it, it goes to show, blindly following without understanding is not smart all the time.